# React native bottom tab navigate to desire screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

First I create Bottomtabs and import in Core navigator;

```
const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
function BottomTabNavigator({ navigation, route }) {


  return (
    <BottomTabs.Navigator>
      <BottomTabs.Screen
        name="ExploreTab"
        component={ExploreNavigator}
      />

      <BottomTabs.Screen
        name="FormScreen"
        component={ProfileNavigator}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabBarLabel: "",
          tabBarButton: (props) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              {...props}
              onPress={() => {
                console.log({ navigation });
                navigation.navigate("FormScreen");
              }}
            >
              <View>
                <Icon
                  type="font-awesome-5"
                  name="plus"
                  size={moderateScale(25)}
                  color={Colors.white}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
      <BottomTabs.Screen
        name="ProfileTab"
        component={ProfileNavigator}
      />
    </BottomTabs.Navigator>
  );
}
export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

The bottom tab navigator is part of the core navigator and the core navigator is the app-level navigator.

```
function CoreNavigator() {
  return (
    <CoreStack.Navigator>
      <CoreStack.Screen
        name="BottomTabNavigator"
        component={BottomTabNavigator}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <CoreStack.Screen name="AboutScreen" component={AboutScreen} />
      <CoreStack.Screen name="WebScreen" component={WebScreen} />
    </CoreStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

when I click on the bottom tab middle plus button. It should navigate to the form screen **FormScreen**.

[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRQYF.jpg)

In simple words below code not working which is present at the Botton tab navigator.
when I click on the bottom plus button Bellow app navigates to ProfileNavigators default screen. I want the app to navigate to FormScreen.

```
<BottomTabs.Screen
        name="FormScreen"
        component={ProfileNavigator}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabBarLabel: "",
          tabBarButton: (props) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              {...props}
              onPress={() => {
                console.log({ navigation });
                navigation.navigate("FormScreen");
              }}
            >
              <View>
                <Icon
                  type="font-awesome-5"
                  name="plus"
                  size={moderateScale(25)}
                  color={Colors.white}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
navigation.reset({
  index: 0,
  routes: [{ name: 'FormScreen' }],
});
```

Instead of navigation.navigate("FormScreen");

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but still navigate to the default screen. But this time screen refreshes every time when I click on plus button.